# wxFrame is missing maximise button

Tags: c++, c, wxwidgets

I'm creating a wxFrame with the following call:

```
new wxFrame(NULL,wxID_ANY,wxEmptyString,wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize,wxCAPTION|wxSTAY_ON_TOP|wxRESIZE_BORDER|wxMAXIMIZE_BOX|wxFRAME_NO_TASKBAR);
```

But although wxMAXIMIZE_BOX is set, there is no related button shown in the title bar of the frame. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: try without wxFRAME_NO_TASKBAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `wxSYSTEM_MENU` for `wxMAXIMIZE_BOX` to have effect under MSW. Arguably, wx might add the former automatically if the latter is specified, just as it already does for `wxCLOSE_BOX` -- but currently it doesn't.